# Play sounds from array every 0.5 sec

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I am building a Simon game, but I get stucked on some point.
I have the array with the currentSequence that contains random sounds from another array. I created methods and properties in order to push random sounds inthe array and play them each 0.5 seconds.

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var game = function() {
  this.power = 0;
  this.start = false;
  this.strict = false;
  this.level = 1;
  this.sounds = [
    "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3",
    "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3",
    "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3",
    "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3"
  ];
  this.wrongMatch = "https://static.mezgrman.de/downloads/wwm/falsch.mp3";
  this.currentSequence = [];
  this.playerSequence = [];

  this.addLevel = function() {
    this.level++;
  }

  this.getcurrentSequence = function() {
    var tot = this.level;
    for (var i = 0; i <= tot; i++) {
      var index = getRandomInt(0, tot);
      this.currentSequence.push(this.sounds[index]);
    }
    console.log(this.currentSequence);
  }

  this.playCurrentSequence = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.currentSequence.length; i++) {
      var audio = new Audio(this.currentSequence[i]);
      audio.play();
    }
  }

  this.reset = function() {
    this.power = 0;
    this.start = false;
    this.strict = false;
    this.level = 1;
    this.currentSequence = [];
    this.playerSequence = [];
  }
}

var simon = new game();

$(document).ready(function() {
  simon.level = 4;
  simon.getcurrentSequence();
  simon.playCurrentSequence();
```

The last 3 lines are for test.
I think I should use a setInterval but now i got stuck and i can't see the solution
Where

Comment: I think it might be better to start playing sound after the last has ended. Check out Audio events on MDN.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Darker/d23q8ahj/)**

I can see you're new, so I rewrote your code to give you better idea on how to write this stuff. Key highlights:

- **Use ES6** - If you're writing a game, you don't need to use 10 years old syntax
- **Use audio events instead of timeouts** - audio emits [`ended`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/ended) event when it's done playing. See all useful events here: [Media Events - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events)
- **Cache created audios** - once you create an audio, put it in some array. You  can rewind old audio using [`Audio.currentTime = 0`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime)

---

```
class Game {
    constructor() {
        this.power = 0;
        this.start = false;
        this.strict = false;
        this.level = 1;
        /** @type {Array<string>} */
        this.sounds = [
            "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3",
            "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3",
            "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3",
            "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3"
        ];
        /** @type {Array<HTMLAudioElement>} cached audios so that we don't create them every time */
        this.audios = [];
        this.audios.length = this.sounds.length;
        /** @type {HTMLAudioElement} */
        this.currentAudio = null;
        /** @type {number} timeout ID returned by setTimeout*/
        this.nextSoundTimeout = -1;
        this.shouldPlaySounds = true;


    }

    startRandomSounds() {
        this.shouldPlaySounds = true;
        this.soundDone();
    }
    stopRandomSounds() {
        this.shouldPlaySounds = false;
        if (this.currentAudio) {
            this.currentAudio.pause();
        }
    }
    /**
     * Called when sound is done playing, next sound will start after that.
     */
    soundDone() {
        if (this.shouldPlaySounds) {
            const soundIndex = Math.floor(this.sounds.length*Math.random());
            /** @type {HTMLAudioElement} */
            var audio = null;
            /// Audio created alread
            if (this.audios[soundIndex] instanceof HTMLAudioElement) {
                audio = this.audios[soundIndex];
            }
            /// Audio not created so create it
            else {
                console.info("Create audio for sound ", this.sounds[soundIndex]);
                audio = new Audio(this.sounds[soundIndex]);
                /// listen when audio is done
                audio.addEventListener("ended", () => { console.info("Done playing"); this.soundDone(); });
                this.audios[soundIndex] = audio;
            }
            this.currentAudio = audio;
            audio.currentTime = 0;
            audio.play();
        }
    }

}
const game = new Game();
game.startRandomSounds();
```

Comment: oh, thank you very much. Just two things. I want to play all sounds that is contained in the array and the number of sounds that are pushed in the array is equal to the this.level value. Then I want to stop.

Comment: Well then all you need to add is a cap for number of sounds played and play multiple sounds at a time. I don't really feel like rewriting the code I have created, I need to work. But I think it's a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Try you function like this:

```
  this.playCurrentSequence = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.currentSequence.length; i++) {
      var audio = new Audio(this.currentSequence[i]);
      setTimeout(function(){audio.play();}, 500);  // This is the change I did.
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the audio ended event so it fires as soon as the previous audio file is done. This would allow you to increase the difficulty of the game with each level and speed up the game and have the next audio fire at the correct time.

```
this.playCurrentSequence = function(index) {
    var that = this;
    let audio = new Audio(this.currentSequence[index]);
    audio.onended = function(){
        if(that.currentSequence.length > index)
            that.playCurrentSequence(++index);
    }
    audio.play();
  }
```